# Selenium Webdriver file attachments

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing some automated testing with selenium webdriver in eclipse. I need to attach actual files and then send them. The problem is these files can't be on my local drive since the completed tests are uploaded to a server so that they can be ran continuously and the connection to my local files will be lost causing the tests to fail. Is there a way to include these test files in the eclipse project in some folder then use the tests to attach or upload these files?

Comment: If the files are under source control, then both your local environment and also the remote CI server will both have access to the files.

Comment: the files will be in the project folder which will be uploaded and then used by the server and downloaded by other users, the root folder for the other users won't be the same so I'm guess the idea is to use some sort of relative path like ../../src/test/text.txt?

Comment: Yes, if you use Maven or Gradle, then the use of relative paths to the project root are the usual convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can store the files in the resources or res folder of your eclipse project and then reference these using relative paths. In that case you will be making these files part of your repository.

Another way is to leave all the files in a shared folder and point to these from the test cases, so in that case you don't need to commit the files to the repository, we used to make that with big files.

Comment: You can create a "res" folder inside the src folder. Then add your attachments there. You can use following code to upload the content `String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/res/test.pdf; driver.findElement(By.id("upload1")).sendKeys(filePath);`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to copy the files to a resource folder within the project and then accessed them using a relative path.