# Upload file from webapp with selenium webDriver

Tags: java, eclipse, file-upload, selenium-webdriver

My project tree

```
Project
    JavaRessources
        src/test/java
            myclass.java
    DeployedRessources
        webApp
            myFile.txt
```

in my class.java i want to upload myFile.txt with selenium webdriver:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("upload1")).sendKeys("myFile.txt");
```

when i do :

```
private void verifyFile(final String myId, final String src) {
        final WebElement file = this.driver.findElement(By.id(myId));
        final String value = file.getAttribute("value");
        assertEquals("name of uploaded file: ", src, value);
    }
 verifyFile("upload1", "myFile.txt");
```

it return : `name of uploaded file: expected: [myFile.txt] but was []`

so i dont know how to use relative path to upload this file with seleniumWebDriver

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. it works very well. Below is my solution if it helps someone:
the code below:

```
// Find path url of files to upload
final String pathDir = new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath();
final String pathFile = pathDir + "\\src\\main\\webapp\\myFile.txt";
// End find path url of files to upload
driver.findElement(By.id("upload1")).sendKeys(pathFile);
```

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.id("upload1")).sendKeys(filePath);` works!. But I used `String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/resources/test.pdf";` to get absolute file path of the file

Answer (score 0):

As far i understand your question, the sendkeys you're sending only the file name. So try sending the absolute path of the file.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("upload1")).sendKeys("d:\\folder\\myFile.txt");
```

Edited according to your comment:

You need to use relative path of the file to reference it,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("upload1")).sendKeys("./webApp/myFile.txt");
```

Comment: i know that it works with your code but i want that i can acess to this file from eclipse project. because i want it can be functionnel with any machine using my code

Comment: My question looks a bit this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640043/selenium-webdriver-file-attachments

Comment: it does not work same problem name of uploaded file: expected [myFile.txt] but was []

Comment: Does your file got uploaded or no

Comment: i found an exemple here to find the url path of file but i dont know how to do it with java and selenium webdriver http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/817/how-can-i-select-a-file-to-put-into-a-file-field-without-using-the-absolute-path

Comment: show me your code for uploading file including all the actions to upload

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("upload1")).sendKeys("/webApp/myFile.txt"); it works great when i give the absolute url but not relative one

Comment: is there any upload button? are you clicking after sendkeys

Comment: No it's the first action but in my html code i have `<input  id="upload1" type="file" name="file[]" />`

Comment: Then after senkeys, you need to click on the button to upload

Comment: I have a button when i clic at it i can 
choose the file to upload that is all and as i say before it works great with absolute url D:/....

Comment: did you try the relative path as (./file.txt)